# Webkit dropdown box positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the dropdown box (submenu) of my navigation bar to the first letter of the navigation item. I've been playing around with the CSS for a while and can't find a solution. If anyone could help, id really appreciate it. Here is a js fiddle. The CSS for the menu starts at line 65.

jsfiddle.net/vy5mk3p3/

[screenshot_of_what_i_need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX0Om.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the one provided below. You are setting left 50% and the margin-left: -80px; which is causing it to be all scattered. Removed that and add negative left position and it all aligned correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/x550ccu6/1/

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
padding: 4px 0 10px 0;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
left: -30%;
width: 260px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
-moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
-o-transition: all .3s .1s;
transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

Comment: its seems to be aligned for the first 3 links but the later ones are still not. thanks for helping out. greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm trying to make the text of the submenus align with the text of the main menus.

Comment: @ErickYe just replace `left: -30%;` with `left: -15px;`

Comment: damn it worked haha thanks so much man!

Comment: @ErickYe np, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted. Check the green check mark below the upvote down vote arrows! Welcome to the community!